# Is there a legitimate reason why 100K+ of data would be sent/received in NTP requests?

Tags: ntp

I'm looking at some network activity and noticing a lot of supposed NTP traffic sending payloads of 100K+ bytes of data and receiving the same amount right back.

Representative sample of a larger payload:

`192.168.x.x    123     66.207.226.14   123     1,165,384   1,165,384`

My first thought was NTP reflection but the consensus on that seems to be a small payload should be sent so that a large response is leveraged at a spoofed recipient. However this was relevant 4 years ago and I'm wondering if what I'm seeing now is some new novel form of NTP abuse (that is being returned to sender because the targeted servers aren't vulnerable?).

I'm not sure what to make of this and don't have pcap to confirm. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is this on TCP or UDP? NTP reflections work on UDP (it is much more difficult to spoof a source IP on TCP) and make no sense if the original payload is big. Are you sure it is really NTP traffic? Any process could use this port and exchange other stuff. You need to run something to really analyze the content of the packets exchanged if you want to debug this. Try to run an NTP clients towards the two endpoints to see if they really answer NTP queries (`66.207.226.14` was not replying to my NTP requests).

Comment: @PatrickMevzek It's UDP. I'm not convinced it's NTP traffic and unfortunately I'm working this off of router flow data instead of anything that would facilitate real analysis. I like your idea of probing the endpoints though.

Comment: The IP PTR is `quake.intrstar.net.` so maybe an hint it is more game related than NTP related...

Comment: Someone has discovered that you allow unrestricted port 123 through your perimeter firewalls and is using it for traffic. As mentioned above, the remote is probably a Quake server based on PTR record. I would hunt down the internal host / user and have a "difficult conversation".

Comment: @Harald what is your basis for this very categorical comment? According to http://www.timegrades.com/30d_66_207_226_14.html 66.207.226.14 (quake.intrstar.net) is an NTP server with an A- rating.

Comment: From only the details provided, it will be difficult to determine whether it is legitimate or not.